# What is basis for the equation : $a-b= \sqrt{(a+b)^2 -4ab}$

Tags: quadratics, computational-mathematics

I've been going through solution which solves about missing two number in array. The solution provider assumes following equation :

> $\displaystyle a-b= \sqrt{(a+b)^2 -4ab}$

I am not sure, what is the base equation from which it has been derived.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all :

$$\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4ab} \color{red}\neq a-b $$

The correct identity is :

$$\displaystyle \sqrt{(a+b)^2-4ab} =|a-b| $$
 $\big(|x|$ denotes [Absolute Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of $x \big)$

This is so because ;

$$\color{blue}{(a+b)^2-4ab}=a^2+b^2+2ab-4ab=a^2+b^2-2ab= \color{blue}{(a-b)^2}$$

Therefore :

$$ \sqrt{(a+b)^2-4ab}=\sqrt{(a-b)^2}=|a-b|$$

Comment: Yes, exactly they probably assumed it to be + .

Comment: @Jaideep Khare : Thank you for the answer. Now, I got it !!!

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is only valid when $a-b\ge0$. It is based on
$$
(a-b)^2 = (a+b)^2 - 4ab 
$$

Answer (score 1):

It certainly means :

$a-b =\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+2ab)-4ab}$
which when you'll solve get $\sqrt{(a-b)^2}$
but it's not only (a-b) but also $|a-b|$

Comment: What do you mean by "also $-(a+b)$"? Square root has only one value.

Comment: ^ I meant it should be mod, since I don't know how to write + and - simultaneously in LeTex

Comment: @ItiShree Use `\pm` for $\pm$

Comment: @JaideepKhare thanks mate!

Comment: It is still not true, $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, not $\sqrt{x^2} = \pm x$. As I said, square root is single valued.

Comment: Well yeah I'll correct that, I forgot that. Thanks.